# Аналог PHP оператора "=>" на C#

Tags: php, c#

Здравствуйте!

Вот код:

```
array(
   "Param1" => "lastname",
   "Param2" => array(
      "Param21" => "name1",
      "Param22" => "name2",
   )
)
```

Вопрос:

как он будет выглядеть в C#? Подскажите аналог этого оператора "=>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точный аналог оператора `=>` в этом контексте - это `{key, value}` при использовании механизма [Collection Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb531208.aspx):

```
var arr = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Param1", "lastname" },
    { "Param2", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Param21", "name1" },
            { "Param22", "name2" }
        }
    }
};
```

Collection Initializer использует duck typing - т.е. он не требует, чтобы с его помощью инициализировали именно `Dictionary<K, V>`. Вместо этого он просто проверяет что инициализируемый объект - это `IEnumerable`, и что у него есть метод `Add` с двумя параметрами.

Пример на php пытается смешать в одном массиве и строки и другие массивы - так что на C# в эквивалентном коде тоже не будет строгой типизации.

Answer (score 4):

Не работал с PHP, но беглый обзор [ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241819/what-does-mean-in-php) показал, что оператор `=>` в PHP используется для создания и извлечения информации из ассоциативных массивов. Эквивалентом в C# может выступать [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Но приведенный Вами пример не получится<sup>1</sup> перевести напрямую в C#, поскольку, согласно [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func), в качестве значения в PHP может выступать объект любого типа. Поэтому, для того, чтобы перевести данный код на C#, Вам необходимо определить общий тип для представления значений в словаре.

Допустим, Вы реализуете некое подобие JSON представления. Тогда Ваш код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var data = new Dictionary<JsonString, JsonNode>
{
    {new JsonString("Param1"), new JsonString("lastName")},
    {
        new JsonString("Param2"), 
        new JsonObject(new Dictionary<JsonString, JsonNode>
        {
            {new JsonString("Param21"), new JsonString("name1")},
            {new JsonString("Param22"), new JsonString("name2")}
        })
    }   
};
```

При условии, что Вы определили иерархию классов, где `JsonNode` выступает в качестве базового, а `JsonString` и `JsonObject` от него наследуются.

---

*<sup>1: Технически, это возможно, если объявить в качестве типа значения [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) или [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx), но учтите, что это может привести к падению производительности и плохо поддерживаемому коду.</sup>*